# How to decrypt User model columns in Laravel as they're queryed from the DB

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I am trying to decrypt certain columns within my `App\Models\User`. For this I have created a trait for the Model to use.

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

trait Encryptable {

    public function getAttribute($key) {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptableColumns())) {
            return Crypt::decryptString($value);
        }
        
        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptableColumns())) {
            $value = Crypt::encryptString($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    
    protected function encryptableColumns() {
        return [
            'name',
            'service_number',
            'team',
            'company',
            'callsign'
        ];
    }

}
```

The issue I am having is that the `$value` being returned from the `getAttribute` method is not decrypted. If I use the `die(Crypt::decryptString($value))` I can see the value is still encrypted.

My `App\Models\User` has the `use App\Traits\Encryptable;`

Any help appreciated.

Update: If I change it to `return 'foo';` all the values become `foo` so it definitely executes the method.

If I run `Crypt::decryptString(Auth::user()->name)` it works so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

So, I am extremely confused but this seemed to fix the issue:

```
return Crypt::decryptString(Crypt::decryptString($value));
```

Comment: That'd indicate that somewhere along the line you've accidentally double-encrypted the value.

Comment: Its all test data so perhaps I should truncate the data and identify where this occurred and go from there? The original post should work as expected? @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

This links might help you. I know it doesnt answer your question but shows a different and easier way to achieve what is needed.

https://github.com/gregoryduckworth/Encryptable